# Issue with memory leak

Tags: c++, visual-c++, raytracing

I'm trying to create a path tracer that can render meshes but I have an issue trying to build a naive bounding volume hierarchy which will help me traverse the mesh and increase performance. However I encountered an issue where whenever I tried to partition the vertices in a mesh recursively (ultimately building a bvh i guess), it led to a memory leak and linked to a cpp file "new_scalar.cpp" telling me there was a stack overflow.

To try to solve the issue, I created another project where I have a node that stores a vector of float pointers and whenever I call partition, it creates two new nodes with half of the split vector each which sort of simulates the recursive nature of building a bvh. Then I encountered the same issue trying to fix it and I don't understand why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

#define print(x) std::cout << x << std::endl;

struct Node {
    std::vector<float*> Numbers;

    Node* LeftNode;
    Node* RightNode;

    void Partition() {
        if (Numbers.size() > 4) {
            // Find center
            float min = HUGE_VALF;
            float max = -HUGE_VALF;

            for (int i = 0; i < Numbers.size(); i++) {
                min = fmin(min, *Numbers[i]);
                max = fmax(max, *Numbers[i]);
            }

            float center = (min + max) * 0.5f;

            // Partitioning
            LeftNode = new Node;
            RightNode = new Node;

            for (int i = 0; i < Numbers.size(); i++) {
                if (*Numbers[i] < center) {
                    LeftNode->Numbers.push_back(Numbers[i]);
                }
                else {
                    RightNode->Numbers.push_back(Numbers[i]);
                }
            }

            LeftNode->Partition();
            RightNode->Partition();
        }
    }
};

struct Object {
    Node* Root;

    void BuildBVH(std::vector<float*> numbers) {
        Root = new Node;
        Root->Numbers = numbers;
        Root->Partition();
    }
};

int main()
{
    srand(std::clock());


    // Initialize vector
    std::vector<float*> numbers;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        float* newNumber = new float;
        *newNumber = ((float)(rand() % 1000000) / 1000000.0f) * 2.0f - 1.0f;

        numbers.push_back(newNumber);
    }


    Object object;
    object.BuildBVH(numbers);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your function `Partition`, you're recursively calling `Partition`:

```
 LeftNode->Partition();
 RightNode->Partition();
```

Whenever you call a function in C++, the return address (and any parameters) are pushed onto the stack.  C++ stack sizes vary from a few kilobytes to several megabytes but aren't really made for deep recursion.  So you don't want to recursively call `Partition` 100,000 times.  Maybe refactor that into a loop?

Comment: So instead of partitioning in a partition function, I should instead make a new one which returns an array of two nodes which I can then call partition on?

Comment: This is untrue though. The function isn't infinite recursion. It won't call right and left node's `Partition()` if the size is less than 4 and thus will immediately return. The recursion is still the issue but it's not infinite.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Correct, answer edited accordingly.  Brings up the point that it makes code more readable, and hence better, to have an explicit `return;` at the end of `void` functions if that's how they actually `return`.

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing 100,000 floats to `numbers` and then call `Partition()` on those. `Partition()` calls `Partition()` for both sides, over and over again (until `Numbers` is less than `4` which still takes a while) . You're simply overflowing your call stack by recursing too many times.

<sub>Side note: Stop using `new` like this.</sub>

Comment: When should I use new in this program? When making the float pointers?

Comment: Use smart pointers instead: [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) along with [std::make_unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) and [std::make_shared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) and you don't use `new` (or `delete`!) at all.

Comment: I haven't looked into smart pointers yet so I'll definitely do some research on those